# Isolating user uploaded contents from other users with Yii

Tags: php, yii, authorization

In my app many users, and they can add articles, articles can contain images, and all images stored in uploads folder, and by default any user can delete any image in folder, certanly its not good, whats is the best way to fix that 
(For example store images in uploads//) or something like that?

Problem is - how i can separate user uploads?

Comment: Think about using a database, everytime a user uploads an image, rename the image and save the information in a database, link that image to the specefic user. And when they try to view the images, read from the database which images belong to him, and of course give him the opportunity to delete his images ... You could add a separate folder for each user under uploads.

Comment: A WYSIWYG editor is probably not the way to go with this... it is fine for helping the user format their content correctly, but for the adding/removal of images, a custom solution is the only option in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the tag yii have a look at [Authentication and Authorization - Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth). It has special support on this topic. Try to stick with your frameworks conventions to achieve what you desire first. This way you'll have a conssistent system and the power of frameworks' community.